# Unexpected whitespace between comments on Mobile Safari

Tags: bug, comments, design, iphone

Whenever you select between two comments "touching" each other, the whitespace in between the two grows larger.

---

[image]

---

I've encountered this bug on: codegolf.SE, SO, meta.SE, meta.codegolf.SE meta.SO, and programmers.SE. I will try to find more sites.

Comment: What browser are you using? What operating system? What versions of both? If you have any extensions/plugins installed, what happens if they are disabled?

Comment: Does it only happen in Code Golf, or also on other sites?

Comment: @Oded I am running the full site on safari on my iphone.

Comment: @ProgramFOX After going to some other sites, it appears to only on beta sites. A few sites I visited, Craft CMS beta, Code Golf beta, CodeReveiw beta.